# Issue in assigning priority to plc based motor

Tags: plc, structured-text

I want to assign a unique priority to each element in an array, but with the snippet below I'm getting the same priority `m` repeated for elements with the same working time values. How do I set a unique priority for each element?

```
// assign priority number according to working times
#m := 0;
FOR #m := 0 TO 10 DO
    FOR #l := 0 TO 10 DO
        IF #OrderedList[#m] = #WorkingTimes[#l]."Time" THEN
            #WorkingTimes[#l].Priority := #m;
        END_IF;
    END_FOR;
END_FOR;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some default priority then exit the inner `FOR` loop when you update an element

```
// assign priority number according to working times

FOR l := 0 to 10 DO
    WorkingTimes[l].Priority := -1;
END_FOR;

FOR m := 0 TO 10 DO
    FOR l := 0 TO 10 DO
        IF OrderedList[m] = WorkingTimes[l].Time AND WorkingTimes[l].Priority = -1 THEN
            WorkingTimes[l].Priority := m;
            EXIT;
        END_IF;
    END_FOR;
END_FOR;
```

I haven't tested this, but the concept should work.

Comment: Facing issue with this code - operator  AND is not compatible with the data type of bool and int

Comment: Hm, Logix Designer is ok with this syntax, but maybe the order of operations is messing with you. Try adding parenthesis around each comparison like this: `IF (OrderedList[m] = WorkingTimes[l].Time) AND (WorkingTimes[l].Priority = -1) THEN`